# Crosswalk Chomium API : Blank View on Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, chromium, chromium-embedded, crosswalk-runtime

as android Wear doesn't support webview i'm trying to use chromium with Crosswalk api xWalkWebView.

But when i try to load an MHT file on wear the screen stays blank and i'm getting the following log (FYI same file is working fine on phone's xWalkWebView)

```
06-09 10:59:22.684: D/XWalkLib(6572): Init embedded mode
06-09 10:59:22.722: D/XWalkLib(6572): lib version, api:5, min api:5
06-09 10:59:22.722: D/XWalkLib(6572): app version, api:5, min api:5
06-09 10:59:23.119: I/LibraryLoader(6572): Time to load native libraries: 83 ms (timestamps 7676-7959)
06-09 10:59:23.119: I/LibraryLoader(6572): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
06-09 10:59:23.119: D/XWalkLib(6572): Running in embedded mode
06-09 10:59:23.119: D/XWalkLib(6572): Init core bridge
06-09 10:59:23.566: I/LibraryLoader(6572): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
06-09 10:59:23.566: I/chromium(6572): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
06-09 10:59:23.577: I/BrowserStartupController(6572): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
06-09 10:59:24.211: I/ResourceExtractor(6572): Extracting resource xwalk.pak
06-09 10:59:24.278: I/ResourceExtractor(6572): Extracting resource icudtl.dat
06-09 10:59:24.590: W/art(6572): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-09 10:59:26.464: W/art(6572): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-09 10:59:27.040: I/art(6572): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC     freed 11345(724KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 28MB/29MB, paused 7.695ms total 228.773ms
06-09 10:59:27.102: I/SWL WearShowWebPage PATH(6572): /storage/emulated/0/swapplauncher/data/webcache/webpage.mht
06-09 10:59:27.322: I/chromium(6572): [INFO:xwalk_extension_renderer_controller.cc(47)] EXTENSION PROCESS DISABLED.
06-09 10:59:28.186: W/art(6572): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-09 10:59:28.440: W/BindingManager(6572): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6572
```

the error seems to be here:

```
06-09 10:59:27.322: I/chromium(6572): [INFO:xwalk_extension_renderer_controller.cc(47)] EXTENSION PROCESS DISABLED.
06-09 10:59:28.186: W/art(6572): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
06-09 10:59:28.440: W/BindingManager(6572): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6572
```

i have tried with both beta and not beta latest versions and some olders ones.

i have tried with various webpages and a simple Hello World html file.

If you can't help about this issue, you may also point me to another solution to use chromium on wear.